# Magnet links opens up Opera error dialog - Yet Opera was removed!

Tags: uninstall, opera

I have an odd problem.

I installed a new version of Ubuntu 14.04 and Mate Desktop. Clicking a magnet link opens up a error message form Opera (unable to open profile - you don't have permissions, bla bla).

Thing is that I removed Opera; purged opera, ran apt-get autoremove; apt-get update; and still that thing shows up!

I guess my question is HOW to remove Opera EVEN when it's already removed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think permissions have been changed to root on the config and cache folders. If you want to reinstall Opera, you can just delete them:

```
sudo rm -R ~/.config/opera ~/.cache/opera
```

Or, you can try to change back permission, and then start Opera and see if it works:

```
sudo chown -R yourUsernameHere ~/.config/opera ~/.cache/opera
sudo chmod -R 700 ~/.config/opera ~/.cache/opera
```